# Database repository containing queries

Tags: db.databases, data-sets

For my research, I need to find real database queries (just queries, I do not need the data). However, the unique public "real" queries I know are those appearing in the TPC benchmarks.

Does any of you know of any public database that also shows some real queries (e.g., a SQL database with some SQL views defined over it)? I do not care if they are in SQL, or SPARQL. My main concern is that they should be first-order.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I think that it would be useful to take a look at the following papers (and their related works sections):

- François Picalausa and Stijn Vansummeren. What are real SPARQL queries like? In SWIM, 2011.
- Angela Bonifati, Wim Martens, and Thomas Timm. An Analytical Study of Large SPARQL
  Query Logs. PVLDB, 11(2), 2017
- Silviu Maniu, Pierre Senellart, Suraj Jog:
  An Experimental Study of the Treewidth of Real-World Graph Data. ICDT 2019: 12:1-12:18